# How to Check if String Has the same characters in Python

Tags: python

What is the shortest way to check if a given string has the same characters?

For example if you have `name = 'aaaaa'` or `surname = 'bbbb'` or `underscores = '___'` or `p = '++++'`, how do you check to know the characters are the same?

Comment: @Moses Koledoye: Not a possible duplicate. Check the answers again.

Comment: Did you check the answers in the dupe? Closing a question as dupe does not mean your question was not well received, it's a way of making SO Q & As less dispersed.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: Your dupe target looks fine to me... and now I feel a bit embarrassed for answering instead of looking for a dupe target myself. :oops: :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An option is to check whether the set of its characters has length 1:

```
>>> len(set("aaaa")) == 1
True
```

Or with `all()`, this could be faster if the strings are very long and it's rare that they are all the same character (but then the regex is good too):

```
>>> s = "aaaaa"
>>> s0 = s[0]
>>> all(c == s0 for c in s[1:])
True
```

Comment: WOW! This is it! Pythonic! I have added `len(set(s.lower())) == 1` to take care of case-mixed strings.

Comment: With the `all` version, it'd be _slightly_ faster if you assign `s[0]` to a local outside the gen exp. And you don't need to do the `len(s) == 1 or` part, because `all` on an empty iterable returns `True`. Eg `all(False for i in range(0))` returns True because the condition isn't false for any of the (non-existent) items.

Comment: @PM2Ring: right

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex for this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^(.)\1*$')     

re.search(p, "aaaa") # returns a match object
re.search(p, "bbbb") # returns a match object
re.search(p, "aaab") # returns None
```

Here's an explanation of what this regex pattern means: https://regexper.com/#%5E(.)%5C1*%24

Answer (score 3):

Also possible:

```
s = "aaaaa"
s.count(s[0]) == len(s)
```

Comment: I benchmarked them all and this is by far the fastest solution offered here, and simple in code too.

Answer (score 1):

```
compare == len(name) * name[0]

if(compare):
    # all characters are same
else:
    # all characters aren't same
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways.

```
def all_match0(s):
    head, tail = s[0], s[1:]
    return tail == head * len(tail)

def all_match1(s):
    head, tail = s[0], s[1:]
    return all(c == head for c in tail)

all_match = all_match0

data = [
    'aaaaa',
    'bbbb',
    '___',
    '++++',
    'q',
    'aaaaaz',
    'bbbBb',
    '_---',
]

for s in data:
    print(s, all_match(s))
```

**output**

```
aaaaa True
bbbb True
___ True
++++ True
q True
aaaaaz False
bbbBb False
_--- False
```

`all_match0` will be faster unless the string is very long, because its testing loop runs at C speed, but it uses more RAM because it constructs a duplicate string. For very long strings, the time taken to construct the duplicate string becomes significant, and of course it can't do any testing until it creates that duplicate string.

`all_match1` should only be slightly slower, even for short strings, and because it stops testing as soon as it finds a mismatch it may even be faster than `all_match0`, if the mismatch occurs early enough in the string.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `Counter` (High-performance container datatypes).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'aaaaaaaaa'
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> len(c) == 1
True
```