# How to repeat some operation without knowing how many times it has to be repeated?

Tags: python

For example:

I want to know if some input number has only repeated digits or not. So, if the input number was "222", the program would return something like "Repeated digits", if input number was "2224", the program would return "Not fully repeated digits..."

The ideal code would be something like this:

```
number=int(input("Insert the number: "))

if (str(number)[0]==str(number)[1]==...str(number)[len(str(number))-1]):
    print("Repeated digits")
else:
    print("Not fully repeated digits")
```

But I don't know how many characters the input number would have, so the program should len that and put that amount of times in the if function.

Comment: That's a very, very, very basic question, so instead of giving a solution, I propose to give hints: use a `for` loop and iterate through every digit of your number.

Comment: @nostradamus: There are much faster ways to do it, as the answers in the linked question show. Curiously, [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39634415/4014959) was posted by another person yesterday.

Comment: Agree, but as a complete beginner, looping through every digit might be more intuitive and lead to a steaper learning curvbe. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, amazing! Thanks.